# Play Framework - Form not Binding to Nested Tuples

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework-2.0, datatables

I have created a Form to bind to the datatables request:

```
val datatableForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "draw" -> number,
    "start" -> number,
    "length" -> number,
    "search" -> tuple(
        "value" -> text,
        "regex" -> boolean
    ),
    "columns" -> seq(tuple(
        "data" -> number,
        "name" -> text,
        "orderable" -> boolean,
        "search" -> tuple(
            "value" -> text,
            "regex" -> boolean
        )
      )
    ),
    "order" -> seq(tuple(
        "column" -> number,
        "dir" -> text
      )
    )
  )
)
```

In my request I call `val form = datatableForm.bindFromRequest`. This works great for the `draw`, `start`, and `length` variables, but it fails for the `search`, `columns`, and `order` variables. For example, when I do not use nested tuples I can call `datatableForm.bindFromRequest.get` and it will return a `Some` object, but when I add the nested tuples and call `get`, it returns a `None` object.

The data that is sent from the datatables javascript object is:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "columns": [
    {
      "data": 0,
      "name": "",
      "searchable": true,
      "orderable": true,
      "search": {
        "value": "",
        "regex": false
      }
    },
    {
      "data": 1,
      "name": "",
      "searchable": true,
      "orderable": true,
      "search": {
        "value": "",
        "regex": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "order": [
    {
      "column": 0,
      "dir": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "start": 0,
  "length": 10,
  "search": {
    "value": "",
    "regex": false
  }
}
```

This is the data in the body of the request:

```
Map(draw -> ArrayBuffer(1), columns[0][data] -> ArrayBuffer(0), columns[0][name] -> ArrayBuffer(), columns[0][searchable] -> ArrayBuffer(true), columns[0][orderable] -> ArrayBuffer(true), columns[0][search][value] -> ArrayBuffer(), columns[0][search][regex] -> ArrayBuffer(false), columns[1][data] -> ArrayBuffer(1), columns[1][name] -> ArrayBuffer(), columns[1][searchable] -> ArrayBuffer(true), columns[1][orderable] -> ArrayBuffer(true), columns[1][search][value] -> ArrayBuffer(), columns[1][search][regex] -> ArrayBuffer(false), order[0][column] -> ArrayBuffer(0), order[0][dir] -> ArrayBuffer(asc), start -> ArrayBuffer(0), length -> ArrayBuffer(10), search[value] -> ArrayBuffer(), search[regex] -> ArrayBuffer(false))
```

How do I get the Form to bind to the nested tuples?

Comment: Can you cover your form with `@form` ?

Comment: What version of Play it is? I tried it with 2.3 and sending provided JSON with a REST client worked like a charm. Everything is bound correctly.

Comment: @DanielOlszewski I am using Play 2.3. Could you post what your request looks like and a little bit more details about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw this same error. The problem was the request was not being sent as `json`. Make sure to set the `contentType` to `json`.

If you are using jQuery, the documentation is located [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on how to do that.

Essentially something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: youUrl,
  data : data,
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: That helped thank you however with today's Datatables (using serverSide processing which the OP appears to be using) you will need to add the following as well: ```"data": function ( d ) { return JSON.stringify( d ); }``` in order to get the Json you expect to be in the POST body